# Pyplot how to reduce xticks *and* xticklabels density?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot several curves with very high xtick density, say 1000 date strings. To prevent these tick labels overlapping each other I manually set them to be 60 dates apart. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts_index = pd.period_range(start="20060429", periods=1000).strftime("%Y%m%d")

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
tick_spacing = 60

for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(ts_index, 1 + i * 0.01 * np.arange(0, 1000), label="group %d"%i)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title(r'net value curves')

xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::tick_spacing])
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels[::tick_spacing])


plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.xlabel(r'date')
plt.ylabel('net value')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

fig.savefig(r".\net_value_curves.png", )
fig.clf()
```

I'm running this piece of code in PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.2 with a Python 3.6 kernel. Now comes the funny thing: whenever I ran the code in the normal "run" mode (i.e. just hit the execution button and let the code run "freely" till interruption or termination), then the figure I got would always miss xticklabels:
[image]

However, if I ran the code in "debug" mode and ran it step by step then I would get an expected figure with complete xticklabels:
[image]

This is really weird. Anyway, I just hope to find a way that can ensure me getting the desired output (the second figure) in the normal "run" mode. How can I modify my current code to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way to do this is to set a locator.

Comment: @MadPhysicist could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Yes, I'll post something in a bit. no idea why the two modes work differently though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x axis data are strings. Hence you will get one tick per data point. This is probably not what you want. Instead use the dates to plot. Because you are using pandas, this is easily converted,

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(ts_index, format="%Y%m%d")
```

You may then get rid of your manual xtick locating and formatting, because matplotlib will automatically choose some nice tick locations for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts_index = pd.period_range(start="20060429", periods=1000).strftime("%Y%m%d")
dates = pd.to_datetime(ts_index, format="%Y%m%d")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(dates, 1 + i * 0.01 * np.arange(0, 1000), label="group %d"%i)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title(r'net value curves')

plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.xlabel(r'date')
plt.ylabel('net value')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However in case you do want to have some manual control over the locations and formats you may use `matplotlib.dates` locators and formatters.

```
# tick every 3 months
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))
# format as "%Y%m%d"
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y%m%d"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the [`Axis`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#axis-objects) object computes and places ticks using a [`Locator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#ticker) object. `Locator`s and `Formatter`s are meant to be easily replaceable, with appropriate [methods](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#formatters-and-locators) of `Axis`. The default `Locator` does not seem to be doing the trick for you so you can replace it with anything you want using [`axes.xaxis.set_major_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator). This problem is not complicated enough to write your own, so I would suggest that [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) fits your needs fairly well. Your example seems to work well with `nbins=16` (which is what you have in the picture, since there are 17 ticks.

You need to add an import:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
```

You need to replace the block

```
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::tick_spacing])
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels[::tick_spacing])
```

with

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=16))
```

or just

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(16))
```

You may want to play around with the other arguments (all of which have to be keywords, except `nbins`). Pay especial attention to `integer`.

Note that for the `Locator` and `Formatter` APIs we work with an `Axis` object, not `Axes`. `Axes` is the whole plot, while `Axis` is the thing with the spines on it. `Axes` usually contains two `Axis` objects and all the other stuff in your plot.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately your line of code doesn't work correctly, in that it only preserves the *first* several ticks. The labels are expected to be 17 dates that are 60 days apart from `20060429` to `20081214` but now they are the first 17 consecutive dates from `20060429` placed on incorrect locations.

Comment: @Vim. It's been a while since I've worked with this part of MatPlotLib. I'll ping you in a bit after I've fixed it. I've either got the wrong Locator entirely or I'm  not configuring it right. I'll have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of the xticks-labels to `False`

```
for label in plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::N]:
                label.set_visible(False)
```

This will set every Nth label invisible.

Comment: This doesn't change the ticks however, so the `grid` would still be too dense horizontally.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the goal was to reduce xticks-label density. So I probably did't get the question.

Comment: Also, this turns off the visibility of every Nth label instead of the other way around

Comment: You don't need a loop if you use `plt.setp` by the way.

Comment: `k = plt.gca().xaxis.get_ticklabels(); plt.setp(k, visible=False), plt.setp(k[:,:,N], visible=True)`. Just for future reference, since this is not what OP wants