# Pyplot reducing number of x-axis ticks and labels WITH ZOOMING

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib.pyplot, I would like to know how to reduce the number of x-ticks and corresponding labels ***that automatically scales/re-populates X-axis while zooming***.

I import it using
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

What I mean by while zooming is: "If I zoom in, to a particular location on the plot, it should show me the closest x-axis values near that point."

My data is a spreadsheet(pandas df from CSV). I have over 1000 temperatures and timestamps logged by an arduino. I want to plot these to see the exact moment my sensors start behaving weirdly.

[image: This is the dataframe]

If I plot it normally, the plot takes too much time to load, it is sluggish to zoom and pan etc, BUT, when I zoom in, it shows me the nearest X-axis labels properly(since I did not hide them/do anything yet).

**Code:**

```
plt.close()
plt.plot(df_31["Time"], df_31["T_One"], label = "T_1", color = "blue")
plt.plot(df_31["Time"], df_31["T_Two"], label = "T_2", color = "red")
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

**Output:** Can't read a thing when zoomed out.
[image: Standard output, ILLEGIBLE]

**ZOOMED IN:**
[image: Standard, zoomed IN]

If I try `plt.xticks(df_31["Time"][::500])`, it shows me the type of display I want ***Only in home view***. Once I zoom in, the x-axis does not show anything there and it is all quite blank.

**Home view:**
[image: xticks HOME]

**Zoomed IN:**
[image: xticks ZOOMED IN]

I want to see un-cluttered view normally and have it scale and show me appropriate x-axis values when I zoom-in.

Tried solutions:

```
# plt.xticks(df_31["Time"][::500]) # DOES NOT ZOOM.
# plt.locator_params(axis='x', tight = "True", nbins=6) # DOES NOT WORK, error = {'set_params()' not defined for locator of type}
# ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2]) # FOR OOP based matplotlib, not for pyplot.
# plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(250)) # DOES NOT ZOOM.
```

I have read many S.O posts, have tried multiple suggested solutions, but no joy.
**None** of the following links works when zooming in, nobody even mentions the problems faced during zooming in. A few work in standard view, but when I zoom in, everything stops working.

I have read the following links, used the suggestion by [glopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646298/15065496) here: [Changing the tick frequency on the x or y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-the-x-or-y-axis)

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/reducing-number-of-plot-ticks) was the most promising, but did not work, threw an error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74107310/reduce-number-of-x-axis-tick-labels) output looks most similar to the problem I am facing, but his is "R", mine is Python.

[How to adjust 'tick frequency' for string x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128668/how-to-adjust-tick-frequency-for-string-x-axis)

[Pyplot how to reduce xticks *and* xticklabels density?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290456/pyplot-how-to-reduce-xticks-and-xticklabels-density)

[controlling the number of x ticks in pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188264/controlling-the-number-of-x-ticks-in-pyplot)

tried finding a solution for the aforementioned error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522531/matplotlib-locator-params-or-set-major-locator-not-working), could not solve the problem.

https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.locator_params

https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params.html

Most of the above examples are using ax type plotting (including the official one about [PyPLOT API](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html)). I am using plt type plotting.

I am hating matplotlib for this duality. Why does it have to be so confusing?? I have previously tried learning and solely relying on axes.Axes type plotting, but that also needs pyplot module in some places. So what is the use of going complex OOP based programming? I just gave up trying to properly understand and master matplotlib and instead am using band-aids in programming whenever needed. I have a txt file of matplotlib commands that successfully work. I just copy and paste them when needed and edit them to suit my needs. Seaborn, etc are just matplotlib in pretty dresses, so they will be fine for a while, until I need something specific and I'll have to work under the hood, which will again be matplotlib.

I would be grateful is someone can help me out using PLT style plotting. plt is far easier and self contained. It does not need the help of axes.Axes anywhere, whereas axes.Axes needs PLT to work.

Comment: Are your x-values definitely datetime objects and not strings? https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Comment: @RuthC They were strings. I changed them to datetime. Now I get the error 
```float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'``` It does not plot **at all** now.

Comment: There is no reason `plot` shouldn’t work with datetimes.  I suggest opening a new question with a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates that problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RuthC I used ```df_30["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_30["Time"]).dt.time``` to change it to ```datetime.time``` object. Not a ```datetime``` object. Apparently, unfortunately, MATPLOTLIB does not read datetime.time objects. It needs complete datetime objects. I have solved the main problem in the question using this line ```df_30["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_30["Time"], format = "%H:%M:%S")```, but the issue here is that the plot now shows date&time(it shows 01 15:45) in the X-axis(I want it to show HH:MM:SS). I only want the time since all my readings were taken on a single day.

Comment: You can use `DateFormatter` to format the ticks how you like.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_formatters_locators.html#date-formatters

Comment: Thanks a lot @RuthC. I was struggling to get the set_major_formatter to work since I am using plt interface. I finally solved the problem and wrote a long answer explaining how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to [RuthC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501128/ruthc) for guiding me through the comments.

The primary problem(every single timestamp being plotted) was due to the fact that my timestamps were `str` type. Not datetime objects. This caused matplotlib to plot them all.

After changing the format to datetime objects using `df_30["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_30["Time"])`, The df["Time"] was converted to datetime objects instead of strings. The issue however, is that depending on whether you use the `format = "%H:%M:%S` flag or not, the date will either be 01-01-1900 or the current date.

That is: if you convert the strings to datetime objects using
`df_30["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_30["Time"], format = "%H:%M:%S")`
you get time changed from `str` object with value `15:30:00` to `datetime` object with value `1900-01-01 15:30:00`

If you convert the strings to datetime using
`df_30["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_30["Time"])`
you will get the `datetime` object with value `2023-11-07 15:30:00`

If the dates are not of consequence, you can safely ignore them(so long as you neither have your data spanning more than one day, nor do your timestamps cross midnight).

**The problem now** is that the `plt` will show the day *and* time when you plot it(*without seconds*). i.e; the x-axis tick labels will read `01 15:30` or `07 15:30` depending on which method you used to convert the dates.
[image: This is how it looks]

**If** however, you only want the timestamps to be plotted(*or seconds are important*), you need to change the formatting of the x-tick labels of the plot. This is how I did it:

```
plt.plot(df_30["Time"], df_30["T_One"], label = "T_1", color = "blue")
plt.plot(df_30["Time"], df_30["T_Two"], label = "T_2", color = "red")
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.grid(which="major", alpha = 0.45)

thisaxesinstance = plt.gca()
thisaxesinstance.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))

plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image: Required Design]

what the above lines do is:
`thisaxesinstance = plt.gca()` gets the current AXES instance(the plt figure basically) and assigns it to the variable `thisaxesinstance`.
`thisaxesinstance.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))` gets the `xaxis` of the `thisaxesinstance`, and modifies it's formatting using the `set_major_formatter` command. The `set_major_formatter` is told to format the datetime object according to `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")`, which is matplotlib's own in-built datetime module. `"%H:%M:%S"` means `Hour:Minute:Second` format.

In some other StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47059651/15065496), michal.dul suggested using set_major_formatter, but opening matplotlib's [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html) shows that it is the `axes.Axes` type command, not the `plt` type command.

A simple way of explaining it, which helped **me** is: The line `thisaxesinstance = plt.gca()` converts our `plt` type figure to be compatible with `axes.Axes` commands.